# Not able to get the gender in graph api in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

- I am not able to get the gender here in `OnCompleted` function
- I am able to get other params like `id`,`name`,`email`
- Currently app is in Dev mode

---

This was working yesterday.

---

**Code:**

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                                try {

                                    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                                    String accessToken = token.getToken().toString();
                                    String expiresAt = token.getExpires().toString();
                                    String id = object.getString("id");
                                    String gender = object.getString("gender");

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                                }

                            }
                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, email, gender, location, picture.type(large)");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your https://developers.facebook.com/ account, under **App Review** section, click **Start a Submission**, select **user_gender** from **LOGIN PERMISSIONS** and go through submission steps.

After facebook will approve **user_gender** permission, you can use it.

Again in your developer account click **Settings** then **Advanced** and in **Upgrade API Version** 
change the API version your app calls to **v3.1** and using below code, you will get the gender of the user.

```
private void attemptToLogIn() {
   LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "user_gender"));
   LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        makeGraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {

                    }
                });
    }

    public void makeGraphRequest(AccessToken token) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                token, (object, response) -> {
                    try {
                        String gender = object.getString("gender");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name,gender");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your access token need the user_gender permission:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-user_gender