# Why I can't only get gender in Facebook Graph API - android

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using [Facebook api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph) to fetch user's profile informations.

I can get `id` `name` `email` `birthday`, but somehow in response object `gender` doesn't come. I tried to fetch only `gender` in case of limit of parameters, didn't work.

I also checked my profile and I've set my gender before.

Here is response from debug mode: [Click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln1F6.jpg)

**GraphRequest**

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Retrieving data...");
            mDialog.show();

            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    getData(object);
                    //goIfTokenExist();
                }
            });

            //Graph API
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,birthday,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }
    });
```

**getData function (inside of graphRequest)**

```
   public void getData(JSONObject obj) {
    try {
        URL profile_picture = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + obj.getString("id") + "/picture?width=250&height=250");
        Glide.with(this).load(profile_picture.toString()).into(image);

        text.setText(
                "ID: "+obj.getString("id")+"\n"+
                "NAME: "+obj.getString("name")+
                "EMAIL: "+obj.getString("email")+
                "BIRTHDAY: "+obj.getString("birthday")+"\n"+
                "GENDER: "+obj.getString("gender")
                );

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As summary, textView dislay all response except for gender. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short version is: because Facebook doesn't support this in their API.

Comment: But why its exist in documents?

Comment: You  should ask Facebook that.  Maybe the documentation is out of date.  Either way, the linked Q&A claims that a Facebook employee has confirmed this.

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132163/not-able-to-get-the-gender-in-graph-api-in-android/51566787#51566787