# Unable to request user_age_range from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the user age_rage from facebook login. [Android]

I requested Facebook user permission using this code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_age_range", "email"))
```

I tested it with 2 facebook account.

With the account A (created 2 years ago), I couldn't get the age_range.

With the account B (created recently), I get the age_range just fine.

And here is the code I use:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_age_range", "email"))
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
        override fun onCancel() { ... }

        override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {...}

        override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult) {
            GraphRequest(
            result.accessToken,
            "me?fields=name,email,age_range&format=json&access_token=${result.accessToken}",
            null, 
            HttpMethod.GET ,
            { response ->
               safeLog("SAFE_LOG", response.jsonObject.toString())
            }).executeAsync()
        }
    })
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is Facebook didn't grant me that user_age_range permission because, on the asking permission dialog on account A, the age_range wasn't listed at all but it was listed on account B.

Could you guys tell me what went wrong in my code?

UPDATE:

The solution I found before doesn't work anymore but I found the difference between 2 accounts.

The one which has age_range have access token source FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SERVICE

The one which doesn't have age_range have access token source FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_WEB

I've already researched from the official doc here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenSource

but I still have no idea what's causing the problem?

Comment: If it is working fine with one account but not another my guess would be that there is a difference in the accounts, not a problem with your code.

Comment: And both accounts have a role in the app? (Otherwise of course you would need to submit for review first.)

Comment: After your edit, this sounds as if you were simply using an outdated access token? Did you send the user through the login flow again, to create a new one, and actually ask for the new permission you added? Try and remove the app completely from the user’s settings on Facebook, and then log in to it again.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe.

I tried your solution but no luck

I deleted the app from the user application and website page in the account setting then logged in again in the mobile app as you told. Still, don't have the age_range and access token source = FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_WEB

Comment: _“then logged in again in the mobile app as you told”_ - and with both accounts, that explicitly asked to grant access to their age range?

Comment: Yeah, the mobile app did show a dialog that asked for permission. But with the account which couldn't get the age_range, the dialog specifically left out the user_age_range permission. It only said, "this app wants to access to your public profile and email".

Comment: @HauLuu please look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132163/not-able-to-get-the-gender-in-graph-api-in-android/51566787#51566787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure the problem is Facebook didn't grant me that
>   user_age_range permission because, on the asking permission dialog on
>   account A, the age_range wasn't listed at all but it was listed on
>   account B.

AFAIK, There is nothing wrong with your SDK integration. The thing is there are certain permission which is private to the user(An individual Facebook user can decide whether age should be seen to the public or not) Now if the user didn't make the age as public from the settings. Even though app is asking for age permission facebook SDK will not be able to share it with you. However, on the other end, if logged in facebook user provided public access of age from his/her Facebook account, your app can get the age-related information upon accepting the permission dialog from the SDK.

I hope it makes sense to you.